# Can no longer open file browser in chrome remote desktop

Tags: nautilus, google-chrome, mir

I have been accessing and using a remote computer running ubuntu with no problems for a few weeks now. Since yesterday though, it wont let me open the file browser. If i type

```
nautilus .
```

into terminal, I get the following error:

```
Maximum number of clients reachedFailed to connect to Mir: 
Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Maximum number of clients reachedFailed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect 
to server socket: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestion how I can resolve this without restarting the computer?